# POST sessionStorage object with AJAX to Flask

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, flask, flask-mysql

I want to post each and every key with value to a function in the Flask framework to store them in a MySQL database. Would I be able do it this way?

**JQuery**

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{{url_for('savedata')}}", // Function to send data
        data: sessionStorage.serializeArray(),
        success: function(data) {
            window.location.replace("/quit"); // Redirect to another page after saving data
        }
});
```

**app.py**

```
conn = mysql.connect()
cursor = conn.cursor()
@app.route("/savedata"，methods=["POST"])
def savedata():
sql = "INSERT INTO data_table "
data = ""
for (var i = 0; i < sessionStorage.length; i++) {
    var item = sessionStorage.getItem(sessionStorage.key(i));
    data += "item " + "VARCHAR(255)"
}
sql += data
cursor.execute(sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

sessionStorage can't be converted to array

you can do something like this:

```
 var localdata = {};
   for ( var i = 0, len = localStorage.length; i < len; ++i ) {
           localdata[localStorage.key( i )] = localStorage.getItem( localStorage.key( i ) );

    }
```

and in the ajax:

```
data:localdata;
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending madalin's answer, I'd like to point out that you cannot work with `sessionStorage` directly from Flask, but only from you JS code. What you can do is an AJAX POST request with your keys/values from sessionStorage as a JSON string, and then accessing JSON in you Flask view with `request.json` or better [request.get_json](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.Request.get_json):

AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "{{ url_for('savedata', _external=True) }}",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    accepts: {
     json: 'application/json',
    },
    data: JSON.stringify(localdata), // see madalin's answer
    ...
})
```

Flask view:

```
@app.route("/savedata"，methods=["POST"])
def savedata():
    your_json_as_dict = request.get_json()
    ...
```

Comment: In the Flask view, I would retrieve the JSON keys and values as a dictionary right?

Comment: @KimberleyChong yes, as a Python dictionary.

Comment: @KimberleyChong glad it helped! Please, accept my answer and upvote, so that other people know it worked.

Comment: However, I am still encountering problems with it. The code just won't execute the AJAX

Comment: @KimberleyChong it's better if you post a separate question with a minimal working example, otherwise it's hard to find out what's wrong.

Comment: I have asked another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39411383/using-flask-mysqldb-to-insert-rows-into-database-with-ajax)